# My backup is not working when started by Cron

Tags: cron

For some reason, my backup is not working, when it is started by `cron`.

Crontab entry

`0 10 * * * /home/yzT/BackupDaily.sh`

BackupDaily.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync /home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/BackupDaily.ffs_batch
```

I can see cron starting my backup script in `syslog`.

`Oct 20 10:00:01 debian CRON[2589]: (yzT) CMD (/home/yzT/BackupDaily.sh)`

When I run it manually, the backup system (`FreeFileSystem`) creates a log file on my Desktop and I can see updated files in the backup directory. But via `cron` I do not get a logfile nor see any updates.

How can I find/fix the problem?

**edit**

I found the root of the problem. Switched to TTY and run the script, and I get the following message: `Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?`. So, although there is no GUI using the script, it seems the script wants to have access to the GUI application. How can I fix this?

Comment: What makes you think it hasn't run ? @Freds suggestion to output a line into a logfile would be a useful diagnostic tool. In `BackupDaily.sh` you could add `(echo "Backup daily running"; date)>>/home/yzT/bkup.log`

Comment: Compare your interactive `env` with the cron one. Probably something missing, causing the FreeFileSync to error out

Comment: @XTian because the BackupDaily.ffs_batch actually saves a log file on Desktop, and it's not there. And however, if I manually run the script, it is. And basically... because there is no changes at the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the only user on the system, you can just edit your `crontab` (with `crontab -e`) and add `DISPLAY=:0.0` at the top of the file.

Alternatively, you can try running your backup job like so:

`/home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync /home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/BackupDaily.ffs_batch --display=:0.0`

Comment: ok, now it works. Just for the record, the `--display=:0.0` version doesn't work, but adding `DISPLAY=:0.0`does work.

Comment: On Debian, I had to and "env DISPLAY=:0.0" at the begging to make it work.  As in " * * * *  env DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync /home/yzT/Tools/FreeFileSync/BackupDaily.ffs_batch"

Answer (score 0):

Files with extension **.ffs_batch** are an xml text associated with FreeFileSync app. Therefore, there are two correct ways to program it in cron (crontab -e):

```
export DISPLAY=:0; /path_to/FreeFileSync /path_to/file.ffs_batch
```

or

```
/path_to/FreeFileSync /path_to/file.ffs_batch --display=:0.0
```

The error "Unable to initialize GTK +, is DISPLAY set properly?" it is produced by not defining who executes the task, therefore this must be specified:

```
sudo crontab -e
# or
crontab -e
```

You must also specify the hour / minute / second / day / week / month when the task will be executed. Example:

```
0 10 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /path_to/FreeFileSync /path_to/task.ffs_batch
# or
@weekly export DISPLAY=:0; /path_to/FreeFileSync /path_to/task.ffs_batch
```

Source: [Mirror synchronization](https://www.maravento.com/2014/06/sincronizacion-espejo.html)

Answer (score -3):

You need to use 1-59 instead of * in your cron job

```
1 10 * * * /home/yzT/BackupDaily.sh
```

Comment: can you edit your post with the place to put 1-59 ? On a side note, I am not sure this answer the question.

Comment: @yzT another way, make a log record for you cron task. `0 10 * * * /home/yzT/BackupDaily.sh >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: 0 is perfectly valid for any of these fields.

Comment: This answer is wrong on so many levels... "instead of \*" and then you replace the 0, not the \*. And \* and 0 are valid, as Bram pointed out